# Git status - how show/include global summary/stats about how many files are modified, deleted, etc?

Tags: git

When is executed the `git status` command is possible see all the *modified*, *deleted* and more about the files.

Is there a way through the `git status` command (perhaps through parameters) to show either at the bottom or top a global summary/stats about how many files are *modified*, *deleted*, etc?.

Answer (score 3):

`git-status` doesn't allow much customization of the format.

You can get what you want with `git diff --stat` and `git diff --staged --stat`.

Write a little shell script to call `git-status` and `git-diff`, call it something like `git-morestat`, and put it in your PATH.

```
$ cat ~/bin/git-morestat
#!/bin/sh

git status
echo "Staged stats"
git --no-pager diff --staged --stat
echo "Not staged stats"
git --no-pager diff --stat
```

```
$ git morestat 
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   foo

Staged stats
 foo | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Not staged stats
 foo | 2 ++
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
```